# jar file is not executing unless the entire project is included in system

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I have created the automation script in Selenium using Java in Eclipse and have created a jar file by navigating through Export->java->Runnable JAR file-> package required libraries into generated JAR.All this has been done in System A.

I am trying to run the jar file in System B.But unless I dont include the entire project folder into System B.The jar file is not executing.

My question is ,how to run jar file without including the entire project into System B..?

Comment: You should post some code, we are not seating at your side :p

Comment: There is no code issue.The jar file ex:demo.jar  is executing on System A (where the java project was created ).    But  upon double clicking demo.jar file in System B(where java project is not present) ,the jar is not executing .Its not giving any error as well.     But if I copy the entire project in System B ,demo.jar is executing.

Comment: So we are supposed to guess what resource is used in your code somewhere and not in the classpath? I don't see how, sorry.